# Configure Avro with MassTransit and Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, avro, masstransit, confluent-kafka-dotnet

How to configure MassTransit to serialize/deserialize using Avro when producing to, and consuming from Confluent Kafka topics? I saw that Avro serializer/deserializer are in the package `Confluent.SchemaRegistry.Serdes`. Some code examples would be welcomed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To configure MassTransit to use Avro, the way I've done it is using the generated class files (`avrogen`), and then configuring the producer and topic endpoint as shown below:

First, you need to create the client for the schema registry:

```
var schemaRegistryClient = new CachedSchemaRegistryClient(new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    {"schema.registry.url", "localhost:8081"},
});
```

Then, you can configure the rider:

```
services.AddMassTransit(x =>
{
    x.UsingInMemory((context, cfg) => cfg.ConfigureEndpoints(context));
    x.AddRider(rider =>
    {
        rider.AddConsumer<KafkaMessageConsumer>();

        rider.AddProducer<string, KafkaMessage>(Topic, context => context.MessageId.ToString())
            .SetKeySerializer(new AvroSerializer<string>(schemaRegistryClient).AsSyncOverAsync())
            .SetValueSerializer(new AvroSerializer<KafkaMessage>(schemaRegistryClient).AsSyncOverAsync());

        rider.UsingKafka((context, k) =>
        {
            k.Host("localhost:9092");

            k.TopicEndpoint<string, KafkaMessage>("topic-name", "consumer-group", c =>
            {
                c.SetKeyDeserializer(new AvroDeserializer<string>(schemaRegistryClient).AsSyncOverAsync());
                c.SetValueDeserializer(new AvroDeserializer<KafkaMessage>(schemaRegistryClient).AsSyncOverAsync());
                c.AutoOffsetReset = AutoOffsetReset.Earliest;
                c.ConfigureConsumer<KafkaMessageConsumer>(context);

                c.CreateIfMissing(m =>
                {
                    m.NumPartitions = 2;
                });
            });
        });
    });
});
```

You can review a [working unit test](https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/blob/develop/tests/MassTransit.KafkaIntegration.Tests/Avro_Specs.cs#L39) to see further details. I should probably add this to the documentation.

> I wrote this just now to answer this question, I hadn't used Avro until an hour ago.

Also, I used [this article from Confluent](https://www.confluent.io/blog/decoupling-systems-with-apache-kafka-schema-registry-and-avro/) to get things up and running. The `docker-compose.yml` in the linked unit test project configures all the required services.

#### Update

There is also a [complete sample](https://github.com/MassTransit/Sample-Kafka) that uses Avro with Kafka and MassTransit.

Comment: Note: rather than `AvroSerializer<string>`, just use StringSerializer

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I was actually planning to convert the key to something more complex, like a dictionary, that I could use to store headers or something. Maybe. Anyway, thanks :)

Comment: Well, Kafka records themselves do allow headers outside the key/value. Not sure if the dotnet client/masstransit allow accessing those, though

Comment: @OneCricketeer StringSerializer from which namespace/package?

Comment: @esskar In c# it's called Utf8Serializer from Confluent package

Comment: Deserializer.Utf8 is the usage